# Only half of the MongoDB database is being processed in Spring batch

Tags: java, mysql, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a spring boot batch working with a MongoDB database to feed a MySQL database.
I have approximately half of my database being processed by the program but only something like 200 errors in my logs.

The `BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION` table let me know that the process went well (status completed) and display a `READ_COUNT` of 5692 although I have 11800 documents in the database.

Did I forget something in the configuration to prevent from not going through the entire database?

Here is my configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@Import(PersistenceConfig.class)
public class BatchConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ItemReader<CourseData> reader() {
        MongoItemReader<CourseData> mongoItemReader = new MongoItemReader<>();
        mongoItemReader.setTemplate(mongoTemplate);
        mongoItemReader.setCollection("foo");
        mongoItemReader.setQuery("{}");
        mongoItemReader.setTargetType(CourseData.class);
        Map<String, Sort.Direction> sort = new HashMap<>();
        sort.put("_id", Sort.Direction.ASC);
        mongoItemReader.setSort(sort);

        return mongoItemReader;
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor<CourseData, MatrixOne> processor() {
        return new CourseDataMatrixOneProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<MatrixOne> writer() {
        HibernateItemWriter writer = new HibernateItemWriter();
        writer.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
        System.out.println("writing stuff");
        return writer;
    }

    @Bean
    public Job importUserJob(JobBuilderFactory jobs, Step s1) {
        return jobs.get("importRawCourseJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .flow(s1)
                .end()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Transactional
    public Step step1(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory, ItemReader<CourseData> reader, ItemWriter<MatrixOne> writer, ItemProcessor<CourseData, MatrixOne> processor) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<CourseData, MatrixOne>chunk(10)
                .reader(reader)
                .processor(processor)
                .writer(writer)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to add the faultTolerant param to my step without any success

Comment: Just a thought, but do you have a sharded deployment of mogodb?

Comment: Hola! I have some questions about what are you doing: 1) You say you're feeding MySQL with data from a mongo collection, do you think a failure with a particular data my crash the program? 2) What are those 200 errors?

Comment: @PeterBrittain I don't think so, I used the default installation but I will check

Comment: @HéctorValverdePareja The program does not crash : BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION of the batch show a status COMPLETED with only 5k reads. These errors are acceptable ones like a missing field, too few elements in a list etc...

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a memory issue either as when I delete one document from the processed range (0->5692), I then get 5691 results (and still more than 12k in mongoChef or directly in console)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so I solved it today by returning an empty POJO instead of null in my converter when something is wrong with the data. Then I just skip it in the processor.

It is kind of strange that it doesn't stop on the first null encountered though. Maybe some parallelisation of the chunk elements made me read the logs wrong